# jquery draggable - only drag one at a time

Tags: jquery, html, draggable

Have a series of `<img>`'s that I'm giving the user the ability to drag on top of a `<div>`. What I want to do is only allow one image to be moved at a time, at present the user can drag all images specified with `class="draggable"`.

Have tried `destroy()` and `stop()` when the position of an `<img>` has changed but just can't get this to work. Code below, any ideas?

```
    $(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "#container" });
    });

        <div class="promo">
            <div class="promoImg"><img src="prod.png" border="0" class="draggable ui-widget-content"></div>
        </div>

    <div id="image"><!--DRAGGING <IMG> OVER THIS-->
            <img id="test" src="test.png" alt="Please select image" />
    </div>
```

Comment: So if a user drags Image-B , and then drops it over div id=image , you want Image-B not to be allowed to be draggable again?

Comment: Not quite. There's 2 class="promoImg" <div>s - When one of these gets dragged over id="image" I want the other class="promoImg" (that hasn't been dragged) to become disabled. Thanks